# The .map() doesn't waiting till the updateOrderNo() updates the data in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, iteration

Here, I want to create new orderId for ecah item in the cartData.

But the problem is I think is the iteration, the .map() doesn't waiting till the updateOrderNo() saves the new value(orderNo) in the DB. Since, it doesn't fully wait till the updateOrderNo() db updation operation, When the code try to get the new orderNo on second iteration, it's retrieving/getting the same value(orderNo) on second iteration too.

I have shared the console message and MongoDB orderNo document data below.

```
export const createOrder = () => {
    const result = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const cartData = {
        cartId: 1234,
        items: [
            { name: "One" },
            { name: "Two" }
          ]
        };

        await Promise.all(cartData.items.map(async (item, index) => {
           const orderNumber = await getNewOrderNo();
           console.log("index", index, "orderNumber", orderNumber);

           const OrderData = {
              orderId: orderNumber,
              name: item.name,
              subTotalAmount: 1000,
              discountAmount: 0,
              shippingChargeAmount: 10,
              totalAmount: 1010,
           };

           const newOrderData = new Order(OrderData);
           const addedOrder = await newOrderData.save();
           console.log(`addedOrder - index ${index} ::::`, addedOrder.orderId);

           if (addedOrder) {
               const updatedOrderNo = await updateOrderNo();
           }
        }));

           resolve("success");
    } catch (error) {
           console.error('createOrder catch error', error);
           reject(new Error(error));
    }
   });

    return result;
};


export const getNewOrderNo = async () => {
    try {
        const order = await Setting.findOne({ key: "order_no" });
        var str = "" + (order.value + 1);
        var pad = "0000";
        var ans = pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str;

        return order.prefix + "-" + ans;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('getOrderNo catch error :::', error);
    }
};


export const updateOrderNo = async () => {
    const result = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
            const order = await Setting.findOne({ key: "order_no" });
        const newOrderNumber = order.value + 1;

        const updateOrderNumber = await Setting.updateOne(
            { key: "order_no" },
            { $set: { value: newOrderNumber } }
        );

        if (updateOrderNumber.nModified == 1) {
             resolve(newOrderNumber);
        } else {
             console.error(`order_no is not updated in db`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('updateOrderNo catch error :::', error);
        reject('updateOrderNo failed', error);
    }
    });

    return result;
};
```

Setting collection's order_no document data:

```
{
  "_id":  "607840696826c3ca20a491fb",
  "key": "order_no",
  "value": 1000,
  "prefix": "ABC",
}
```

Console/terminal message:

```
index 0 orderNumber ABC-1001
index 1 orderNumber ABC-1001

::: addedOrder - index 0 :::: ABC-1001
::: addedOrder - index 1 :::: ABC-1001
```

But I need the console message to look like this:

```
index 0 orderNumber ABC-1001
index 1 orderNumber ABC-1002

::: addedOrder - index 0 :::: ABC-1001
::: addedOrder - index 1 :::: ABC-1002
```

Comment: Maybe not directly related but relevant: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743) and [Is it an anti-pattern to use async/await inside of a new Promise() constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229)

Comment: Autoincrement in MongoDB is a recurring topic, you might try reading through some of the similar cases to see how other folks are doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mongodb+autoincrement